# How can i play the video in new tab with fixed dimensions

Tags: php, html, css, video

hi i am  trying to play the video in new tab with fixed height and width how can i do that this my code:

```
<a href="uploads/course_videos/sample.mp4" target="_blank">
    <video width="100px">
         <source src="uploads/course_videos/sample.mp4">
    </video>
</a>
```

when i click on `<a>` tag it is opening in a new window but the video size is coming different for different videos...!
example i want the video should play in fixed dimension:
100px  * 200px

what is the best solution for it..?

Comment: use both attribute height and width width="100px" height="200px"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Play with fixed dim</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="uploads/course_videos/sample.mp4" target="_blank">
<video id="video_loc" width="100px" height="200px">
<source src="uploads/course_videos/sample.mp4">
</video>
</a>


</body>
<script>

var vidd = document.getElementById("video_loc");
vidd.play();

</script>
</html>
```

Here you can play video on same page, if you want to play it new window just click on video it will redirect you to new window.

Answer (score 1):

```
video{
object-fit: initial;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
}
```